# Umbraco 7 lists

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I am new to Umbraco, and am trying to get to grips with its concepts, in particular how to create lists. For example, you might want a news listing that appears on a page as a list of headlines with mouseover extra content, but you don't want to be able to click on an item and open a full page, it's just there as a list.

You could create a repeating grid of content on the page itself, but that could become unwieldy.

It looks like (correct me if I am wrong) the Umbraco way is to create a parent page, and each news item to be a child page, which can be edited individually, and use a partial view to list them on the required page.

Is this the recommended approach?
If so, two questions :

1. How do I exclude these news 'phantom' pages from the main navigation - I understand I could set a true/false property on the page with alias umbracoNaviHide and tick this (which excludes it from 'visible' in the queries)
2. If so, how do I prevent direct access to the news page by its url (the umbracoNaviHide does not prevent the page opening)

Presumably these news pages would show in the back end main view as they would be descendants of the home page?

Any advice welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Content Repository` to hold content objects that won't be pages in your application.

Use following steps:

**Step 1: Create the root content repository document type**

Go to your backend to the `Settings` section. Under `Document Types` create a new type and give it the name `Content Elements`. After creating this make sure to check the checkbox of `Allow at root` in order to add this element to your root in the `Content` section.

**Step 2: Add your newly created document type to the root of the content**

Go to the `Content` section and choose to add a new item directly under content ( select the three dots next to `Content` ).

Select your `Content Elements` item, give it a name and click save.

**Step 3: Remove the checkbox allow at root**

You only want to add one `Content Reposity` item to your root where you will place all items like news, jobs, locations,...

Go to the settings of the `Content Elements` document type and remove the checkbox of `Allow at root`.

**Step 4: Create a child repository for each type**

Using your example I will now create a `News` document type which will be a child item of the `Content Elements` repository.

Go to the `Document Types` under `Setting` in your backend and choose to add a new document type. Give it a name `News` and choose save.

In the settings of the `Content Elements` check the checkbox of the newly created `News` item to allow as a child.

**Step 5: Add the news list in your content**

In the content section choose to add a new item under the `Content Elements` using the three dots.

Select the News item, give it a name and choose save.

**Step 6: Create a new document for the news item**

One more item is a `NewsItem` which will hold the properties/information of the item.

Using the same steps of 4 you can easly add this. Be aware that now you have to go to the `News` item where you will add a check to the `NewsItem` checkbox to allow as a child.

Also now define some properties of the newsitem.

**Step 7: Add newsitems in the content**

Using the same steps from 5 you can now add items in the news list.

**Step 8: How to place a content element on to your page**

If you have created a page you can add a property with a `ContentPicker` datatype which can be used to select a item from the `Content Elements` repository. Or using partial views you can create a list from the `News` to get all items.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. The only issue is you can still open the individual newsitem by url (if you can guess the id) rather than return a 401 error. I guess there's no easy way to do that?

Comment: That's strange, in my project I get nicely a 401 error if I try to access an item from the repository. Make sure you don't assign a temlate to your items in the repository